# Setting File Owner to user in a non-trusted domain via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl

I am trying to set the owner of a file to a SID from another another domain.
This domain is Non-Trusted so the following won't work.

```
PS > (Get-Acl .).SetOwner([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]'TESTWORLD\barry')
Exception calling "SetOwner" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."
At line:1 char:1
+ (Get-Acl .).SetOwner([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]'TESTWORLD\barry')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : IdentityNotMappedException
```

I am able to get the SID for the user from the other domain like so:

```
$c = Get-Credentials TESTWORLD.INVALID\AdminUser
$dc = Get-ADDomainController -Discover -DomainName TESTWORLD.INVALID -Service PrimaryDC | %{$_.HostName}
$sid = Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq "barry"} -Server $dc -Credential $c | %{$_.SID}
```

I then want to set this SID to be the owner of that file. How is that possible?

Comment: I don't think you can.  And I can't think of any good reason why a security system would allow that or why you would want to do it.

Comment: @mjolinor - I am mounting a resource from another domain like so: "PS C:\> New-PSDrive -Name TEST -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\FILE01t.TESTWORLD.INVALID\vol01$ -Credential $c". I then create a file at TEST:\Filename and then want to change the Owner from the Credentials specified to another user in the TESTWORLD domain

Comment: Have you tried just re-writing the SDDL string?

Comment: I am by no way a master with SDDL strings but when I tried I got the following: "Exception calling "SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm" with "1" argument(s): "The SDDL string contains an invalid sid or a
sid that cannot be translated."

Comment: Can you start a remote session on said server using credentials native to that domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If DCOM traffic is allowed to the remote computer, try the following. You'll need to set $Path to the local path for the remote system. If you're using alternate credentials, provide a Credential value in the $OptionalCred hash table:

Try this:

```
$Path = "C:\Folder"
$OwnerSID = # SID string goes here #    
$Computer = $env:ComputerName
$OptionalCred = @{
    # Don't use this running against local machine
    #Credential = Get-Credential TESTWORLD.INVALID\AdminUser
}

$EscapedPath = [regex]::Escape($Path)
$FileSecuritySetting = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting -Filter "Path='$EscapedPath'" -ComputerName $Computer @OptionalCred
$Win32SD = $FileSecuritySetting | Invoke-WmiMethod -Name GetSecurityDescriptor | select -ExpandProperty Descriptor

$NewOwner = ([wmiclass]"Win32_Trustee").PSBase.CreateInstance()
$NewOwner.SIDString = $OwnerSID
$Win32SD.Owner = $NewOwner

Invoke-WmiMethod -Path $FileSecuritySetting.__PATH -Name SetSecurityDescriptor -ArgumentList $Win32SD @OptionalCred
```